# Can't set udp source port in docker

Tags: docker, udp

I am using Docker 18.06.1-ce-win73 on windows 10 and trying to perform the following udp operation:

Docker port 10001   -------------->   host port 10620

It is mandatory for the application running on the host to receive packets from the port 10001.

Inside the docker container, using python I bind on the IP ('0.0.0.0', 10001)  and use the socket to send my packets to the host IP on port 16020.

I have also started the container with the argument -p 10001:10001/udp.
Unfortunately, when receiving the packet on the Host application, the origin port is not 10001 but a random one.

Is it possible to force docker to use a specific source port when using UDP from inside the container ?

Answer (score 0):

You can control the container source port, but when you communicate outside of docker, even to your host, the request will go through a NAT layer that will change the source to be the host with a random port. You may be able to modify the iptables rules to work around this NAT effect.

However, if you really need control of the source port like this, you may be better off switching to host networking (`--net=host` or `network_mode: host` depending on how you run your containers), or change to a networking driver like macvlan that exposes the container directly without going through the NAT rules.